# ideas to pass a param to a onClickEvent in a for loop

Tags: android, parameter-passing, onclicklistener

I'm searching for away on how to add a delete Button into my App, and receiving a id from my code in the function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < separated_rows.length; i++) {
separated_entries = separated_rows[i].split("<cut>");
Button btnDelete = new Button(getBaseContext());
                            btnDelete.setText("Löschen");
                            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreen.this);
                                         helpBuilder.setTitle("Id");
                                         helpBuilder.setMessage("Id: " + separated_entries[6]);
                                         helpBuilder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                              @Override
                                              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                  //do nothing
                                              }
                                             });
                                         AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
                                         helpDialog.show();
                                    }
                            });
                            rowOptions.addView(btnDelete);
                            table.addView(rowOptions,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

separated_entries[6] is containing the id that I want to show, as of right now, just in an alert Dialog. But im running into the problem that separated_entries[6] always contains the last ID and not the one matching the current entry, so the button shows for all the items the same id. Would it be possible to just pass the id into the OnClickListener functioner and would it work? If yes, how would i do that?

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this line

```
helpBuilder.setMessage("Id: " + separated_entries[6]);
```

To

```
helpBuilder.setMessage("Id: " + separated_entries[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a delete button per-row?

If so, the simplest thing to do might be to set the tag of each btnDelete to the id of the item you want deleted. After you create the button:

```
Button btnDelete = new Button(getBaseContext());
btnDelete.setTag(Integer.valueOf(someId);
...
```

then in the onClickListener you can retreive that id easily:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  int theIdSetAbove = (Integer)v.getTag();
  ...
```

Also, this should allow you to create one OnClickListener, and share it amongst all your delete Buttons.